# Where are the screw joints in Indigo?

Tags: ros, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use screw joints in indigo, but i'm getting an error saying that 'screw' is an unknown joint type.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204816/where-are-the-screw-joints-in-indigo?/) by [hal9000](https://answers.ros.org/users/21839/hal9000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hal9000](https://answers.ros.org/users/21839/hal9000/) on 2015-03-11**:
Looking for something like this in gazebo/ros:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUz-vOqKxr0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The joint types supported by URDF are (from [wiki/urdf/XML/joint - Attributes](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#Attributes)):

- revolute
- continuous
- prismatic
- fixed
- floating
- planar

It would appear that SDF (Gazebo's modelling format) does support them (and they *are* used in ROS (see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/35525/need-guidance-to-create-a-simple-simulation-in-gazebo/?answer=39724#post-id-39724) answer by John Hsu for example), but this has not been mirrored in / ported to URDF.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hal9000](https://answers.ros.org/users/21839/hal9000/) on 2015-03-12**:
Thanks!  So is there any way to connect to a gazebo screw joint?  Either with some   tags or some plugin?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-12**:
Seems [torso.gazebo.urdf](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/blob/9f7dc4e7562cc3ce06102b50a16f2a5d02a03a6f/pr2_description/urdf/torso_v0/torso.gazebo.xacro#L22-L31) uses `screw` type joints. It places them inside `gazebo` tags, so that would probably work.